# Get date time for a specific time zone using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, date

It seems that JavaScript's Date() function can only return local date and time. Is there anyway to get time for a specific time zone, e.g., GMT-9?

Combining @​Esailija and @D3mon-1stVFW, I figured it out: you need to have two time zone offset, one for local time and one for destination time, here is the working code:

```
var today = new Date();  
var localoffset = -(today.getTimezoneOffset()/60);
var destoffset = -4; 

var offset = destoffset-localoffset;
var d = new Date( new Date().getTime() + offset * 3600 * 1000)
```

An example is here: http://jsfiddle.net/BBzyN/3/

Comment: You don't need to do this at all. Please read my comments about using `UTC` methods.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Convert date to another timezone in javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10087819/convert-date-to-another-timezone-in-javascript)

Answer (score 32, accepted):

```
var offset = -8;
new Date( new Date().getTime() + offset * 3600 * 1000).toUTCString().replace( / GMT$/, "" )

"Wed, 20 Jun 2012 08:55:20"
```

```html
<script>
  var offset = -8;

  document.write(
    new Date(
      new Date().getTime() + offset * 3600 * 1000
    ).toUTCString().replace( / GMT$/, "" )
  );
</script>
```

Comment: var offset = -8;
var d = new Date( new Date() + offset * 3600 * 1000) 
alert(d);
would give me incorrect time of PST (shows 03:06 instead of 10:06 now), anything wrong here?

Comment: @Yang yea, use the `.getTime()` patch in my newest edit. I didn't use a variable in my tests and the `"+"` turned it into a string concatenation. Oh and take the time in UTC which is emulating the different timezone. So the correct one would be `.toUTCString` not `.toString` (which is what `alert(d)` does)

Comment: @Yang paste the exact snippet you're using please. It should show `09:12` anyway (or `08:12` for `-9`)

Comment: I guess what happens is newDate().getTime() already got my local time which is PST.

Comment: ok, I figured out-- you need to have two offset, one for local time and one for destination time. I'll paste the solution.

Comment: @Yang you can use this solution fine as long as you use the UTC methods `getUTCHours()`, `getUTCMinutes()`, `toUTCString()` etc...the problem with `alert(d)` is that it does `alert(d.toString()`, where as you want `toUTCString` in this case.

Comment: is there a way I can get only time, say "08:55"

Comment: Does this take into account daylight savings in both local and destination offsets?

Comment: As Patrick mentioned, this gets iffy with leap seconds and other timezone schenanigans like DLST. I highly recommend E. karim's solution over this one.

Answer (score 37):

You can do this in one line:

```
let d = new Date(new Date().toLocaleString("en-US", {timeZone: "timezone id"})); // timezone ex: Asia/Jerusalem
```

Comment: Thank you, now i can use the getDate() function's

Comment: This is a much better answer than the accepted one, at least these days when all modern browsers support it, as specifying a time zone by name will presumably take daylight savings time into account. (Since different time zones switch on different dates, or do not use DST at all, a simple offset is not enough.)

Comment: It's better to use `undefined` for the locale instead of hard-coding to `en-US`.

Answer (score 6):

```
var today = new Date();  
var offset = -(today.getTimezoneOffset()/60);
```

Answer (score -1):

You can always get GMT time (so long as the client's clock is correct).

To **display** a date in an arbitrary time-zone, construct a string from the UTC hours, minutes, and seconds after adding the offset.

Answer (score -1):

There is simple library for working on timezones easily called TimezoneJS can be found at https://github.com/mde/timezone-js.

Comment: It's deprecated