# spoof browser location to test javascript date localization

Tags: javascript, date, geolocation

I have a script that translates the javascript date.getTimezoneOffset() into a timezone code like "CST", "GMT", etc.  I would like to test this in cases other than CST, so can anyone point the way in spoofing my location to my browser (or a simpler way to get a date that isn't actually local in js)?

I have tried the chrome extension Manual Geolocation hoping it would trick the browser, but no luck.

Comment: Change your system clock's time zone for testing.

Comment: Exactly, change your system time zone - the browser compares (or actually calculates) local time offset to UTC.

Comment: This maybe ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11124322/get-date-time-for-a-specific-time-zone-using-javascript

Comment: Thanks everyone, I get into this state where I am doing something in code so all fixes must be done in code, and I forget about simple fixes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the general screen of your config screen ('metro' interface) of windows 8 you can change the timezone. This will with most browsers also affect the timezone of the `Date`. For other operating systems or versions just do a google search and it should be fairly easy to find. Language settings of browsers will (in general) not affect this.

On windows, right clicking on the time and clicking 'change timezone' is an easy way to get there as well.

Comment: Thanks, I for some reason just didn't think of changing the system clock.